# What triggers the usage of the negative time to live DNS SOA record value?

Tags: domain-name-system, soa-record

I'm reading through the following [dns tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-dns-terminology-components-and-concepts) and it has this example in it:

```
domain.com.  IN SOA ns1.domain.com. admin.domain.com. (
                                        12083   ; serial number
                                        3h      ; refresh interval
                                        30m     ; retry interval
                                        3w      ; expiry period
                                        1h      ; negative TTL
)
```

The description for the `negative TTL` value says this:

> 1h: This is the amount of time that the name server will cache a name error if it cannot find the requested name in this file.

What are the conditions that could trigger the server to cache a name error like this?  An example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The negative caching interval in the `SOA` comes into play when an authoritative server indicated that the requested record did not exist. The specific cases are:

- Replies with a response code of `NXDOMAIN`.
- Replies with a `NODATA` synthetic state, but only forms where a `SOA` record is present.  (`NOERROR` rcode, 0 answers, 1 `SOA` record in authority section + optional `NS` records)

It's common for server software to enforce a locally configured maximum on this value, so even if you have a negative TTL of `86400` the non-existence isn't necessarily going to be cached for that long by remote recursive servers.

The cases are covered by section [RFC 2308](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308) if you want to read further. Read section 2 as a primer, then 5-6.

Comment: IIUC if I request "not.available.example.com" from the authoritative server then it gets cached for the negative time to live?

Comment: Correct. Full recursive servers will reliably cache the non-existence, but behavior of stub resolvers (such as OS resolver libraries) will vary. Windows does, for example. You would find "Name does not exist." in the output of `ipconfig /displaydns`, which represents `NXDOMAIN`. You'll find instances of "No records of type X" in that output as well, which corresponds to `NODATA`. Most UNIX based systems do *not*, because they do not cache at all without additional configuration. (`nscd` with caching enabled, local recursive server and using 127.0.0.1 for DNS lookups, etc.)

Comment: So if I'm imagining the purpose correctly, is it to be able to double check that "not.available.example.com" really was not available according to the full recursive server?  In other words if I don't get an ip address, I can query the server at something like a /displaydns endpoint, and the result should contain confirmation that the address does indeed not exist?

Comment: `ipconfig /displaydns` exists to tell you the contents of the local stub resolver cache. No more, no less. What admins might want to do with that info is open ended.

Comment: @Ole The purpose is to prevent repeated queries for the name, once the server has already told the resolver that it doesn't exist. Just like any other caching.